# Symfony - adding hardcoded value to collection

Tags: php, symfony, collections, many-to-many

I have ManyToMany relation between my `WorkspaceUser` table and `Role` table like:

```
<entity name="Role" table="role">
... 
    <many-to-many field="workspaceUser" target-entity="WorkspaceUser" inversed-by="workspaceMemberRoles" fetch="LAZY">
        <join-table name="workspace_user_role">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="role_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="workspace_user_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

and

```
<entity name="WorkspaceUser" table="role">
    ... 
    <many-to-many field="workspaceUserRoles" target-entity="Role" mapped-by="workspaceUser" fetch="LAZY"/>
```

My goal is that other than a basic `USER_ROLE` all roles will come from the database rather than being hardcoded.

Byt, how can I hardcode `USER_ROLE` so it can be returned with every user by default?

I assume that adding it within Collection is a way to go? Can someone please help?

```
/**
 * @return Collection<int, Role>
 */
public function getWorkspaceUserRole(): Collection
{
    return $this->workspaceUserRoles;
}

public function addWorkspaceUserRole(Role $workspaceUserRole): self
{
    if (!$this->workspaceUserRoles->contains($workspaceUserRole)) {
        $this->workspaceUserRoles[] = $workspaceUserRole;
        $workspaceUserRole->addWorkspaceUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relation between 2 Entities, using a foreign key constraint you can not have an Entity of that type added.

However, you can dynamically add that role when getting the Roles like this.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// ...

/**
 * @return Collection<int, Role>
 */
public function getWorkspaceUserRoleForSecurity(): Collection
{
    // Make a clone of the roles, otherwise the extra role may be stored in the database
    $roles = new ArrayCollection($this->workspaceUserRoles->toArray());

    $userRole = new Role("USER_ROLE");
    if (!$roles->contains($userRole)) {
        $roles->add($userRole);
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

There are other ways to do this, this may not be the most elegant way of doing this, but it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Leroy I thought this might work but seems that there are several problems.. The Collection is an interface (cannot be instantiated) ..

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't test it. But I've updated the answer.